# Alternate items in n* arrays merge

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have one large array which contains several other arrays. For example

```
let allLines = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h']];
```

I need a function that merge arrays items and append its possible combinations in textarea. They need merged like this:

```
[a, c, f]
[a, c, g]
[a, c, h]
[a, d, f]
[a, d, g]
[a, d, h]
[a, c, f]
...
```

All possible combinations should generated in loop and append it to textarea. In this example possible 18 combinations. I have tryed something like this:

```
let lengths = allLines.map(function(a){return a.length;});
let biggest = Math.max.apply(null, lengths);
a = [];

for (let i = 0; i < allLines.length; i++) { 
   for (let j = 0; j < biggest; j++) {
     if(allLines[i][j] == undefined) {
         break;
       }
       a[i] = allLines[i][j];
     }
     // console.log(a);
  }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could build a cartesian product.

```js
const
    values = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h']],
    result = values.reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []));

result.map(a => console.log(...a));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses `Array.map()` to iterate the arrays recursively, and add items to the sub arrays. The end result should be flattened by the numbers of subarrays - 1.

```js
const fn = ([base, ...arrs], prev = []) =>
  base.map(item => arrs.length ? fn(arrs, [...prev, item]) : [...prev, item])

const getPermutations = arrs => fn(arrs).flat(arrs.length - 1)
  
const allLines = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h']]

const result = getPermutations(allLines)

console.log(result)
```